# Minizinc: counting number of different variables in array associated with initial output array

Tags: arrays, constraints, minizinc

I'm trying to count occurrences within an array that are constrained by first having the same value in the array then by the number of different variables found an associated array.

I am starting with this model

```
set of int: OPTS = 1..4;
set of int: ASSIGN = 1..12;

array[ASSIGN] of var OPTS: result;
```

that can generate a result `[ 1,2,1,3,3,4,1,3,1,1,2,4 ]`

and would like to combine with these statements

```
enum CONDS = {A,B,C,D};
array[ASSIGN] of CONDS : const = [A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C,D,D,D];

array[OPTS] of var 0..max(CONDS): result2;

output ["\(result) \(result2)"]
```

and produce an output that counts how many different `CONDS` appear for each `OPTS`

`[ 1,2,1,3,3,4,1,3,1,1,2,4 ] [3,2,2,2]`

implying that OPTS[1] is associated with at least one of A,C and D, OPTS[2] has As and Ds, OPTS[3] has Bs and Cs, and OPTS[4] has Cs and Ds. I've scrambled my brains a bit with this and earlier questions and can't determine whether to look at creating a less complex constraint, or a more complex one. I could have missed a simple trick here...or maybe it's not so obvious?

I would love to know why my attempt with the following produces unsatisfiable when `X = j`, `[0,0,3,0]` when `X = 1` and '[0,0,0,0]' when `X = i` (which would make east sense to me, but clearly I don't know how this position 'X' is supposed to work with the rest).

```
constraint forall(i in OPTS, j in CONDS)(
   result2[i] = 
     count([ k == j /\ result[k] = i | k in const],X)
);
```

Comment: You write "OPTS[1]", "OPTS[2]", "OPTS[3]" but means "result2[1]" etc, right?

Comment: For your additional question, what is `X` in the loop? Ah, I see what you mean now. I'll update my answer...

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Actually, both I'd say. `results[]` I see as holding the count, while `OPTS{}` are the values that appear in `result[]`, which then has corresponding `CONDS` A to D found in `const[]`. If that makes sense?

Comment: @MikeyB I've now updated the answer to answer the additional question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a model that solves your original question. The construct `card({const[i]  | i in ASSIGN where result[i]=o} )`, counts the number of different values of OPTS with the **set** comprehension `{....}`, using `card` (the cardinality of the set) to do the counting.

```
include "globals.mzn";

set of int: OPTS = 1..4;
set of int: ASSIGN = 1..12;

array[ASSIGN] of var OPTS: result = [1,2,1,3,3,4,1,3,1,1,2,4];

enum CONDS = {A,B,C,D};
array[ASSIGN] of CONDS : const = [A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C,D,D,D];

array[OPTS] of var 0..max(ASSIGN): result2;

solve satisfy;

constraint 
   forall(o in OPTS) (
        % count the number of different CONDS for this OPTS value o
        result2[o] = card({const[i]  | i in ASSIGN where result[i]=o} )
   )
;

output [
    "result:\(result)\n",
    "result2:\(result2)\n",
];
```

The solution is

```
result:[1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4]
result2:[3, 2, 2, 2]
```

**Update: Answer to the additional question**

You asked why this constraint don't give the proper answer:

```
constraint forall(i in OPTS, j in CONDS)(
   result2[i] = 
     count([ k == j /\ result[k] = i | k in const],X)
);
```

Here are some problems with this approach.

First I should say that this kind of loop might in general be a good approach, but the problem statement requires that we count the **number of different chunks** (were each chunk contains many values), not the number of all occurrences.

1. The `k in const` loops through all the values `A,A,A,B,B,...` (not the indices) which mean that`result[k]` is interpreted as `result[A] ... result[D]` which is then translated to as `result[1] ... result[4]` (A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4) which is not what you want.

   Instead, `k` should loop though `ASSIGN` and instead of the plain`k` is should then be `conds[k]`.
2. Another problem is that `result2[i]` is evaluated  for every `j in CONDS`, i.e. it do "double counting" which almost always mean trouble. (Note also that in constraint programming values are never updated. If one got one value in `results[i]` in one loop and another value in another, then the model is UNSAT.)

   Instead a nested loop should be used:

```
constraint
forall(i in OPTS) (
   forall(j in CONDS) (
      % ...
   )
);
```

3. However, using `count` (or `sum`) means that you count all the
   occurrences of the `CONDS`, e.g. for the value `1` this counts
   two `A`'s (from the first chunk) which is not correct.

To fix this one have to just count one occurrence of the `CONDS`. In the model above I use the set approach. Here's another way, using `exists` which just count one of each matching `CONDS` values.

```
constraint 
   forall(o in OPTS) (
      result2[o] = sum(c in CONDS) (
         exists(k in ASSIGN) ( const[k] = c /\ result[k] = o)
      )
   )
;
```

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Thanks for the tip, David. I've fixed it now.

Comment: A general question about how `forall()` works. Does `forall(i in const)` mean `i` is cycles through A,A,A,B,etc, or is it the index, so I would have to use `const[i]` in order to get the letters? Is this different for sets, say if I did `forall(i in CONDS)`?

Comment: I don't suppose there's a way to log some output what a certain expression of formulation points to or is interpreted as, as I would with javascript, say if I had to do some tricky `setA[arrayA[setB[i of arrayB]]]` assertion or equality?

Comment: @MikeyB `forall(i in const)` loops **once** over the elements in `const`. They take the values of the array, here `A`, `A`, ... etc.

Comment: @MikeyB There's a `trace(expression)`, e..g. `constraint   forall(c in CONDS) (trace("c:\(c)\n"));`. Note that for decision variables the output might be uninformative.and prints as `X_INTRODUCED_309_o`. I mainly use it for checking indices in the loops, etc.

Comment: Thanks, may come in handy!

Comment: Regarding the `forall(i in const)`, if `i` become `A` etc., how can I get the index position if I needed it to check against another array or set of same length?

Comment: `ASSIGN` is the values of the indices of `const` (and `result`). You can also use `i in 1..length(const)`, the more general `i in index_set(const)'.

Comment: @MikeyB You should really read the MiniZinc tutorial/manual. it includes most of these questions.

Comment: I have started the Coursera course and keep searching the manual but struggle to dig out the piece of the puzzle I need in amongst the whole blob of text. I know what I ask about is touched on in them, but there is always a cloud of uncertainty about how exactly I should interpret some things. By tackling real-world problems and getting your feedback I am able to fast-track the learning process. For example, your last point about using `1..length()`, which I swear hasn't been touched on yet in the material, was precisely what I needed to understand and solve this next little problem.